# Javascript match with wildcard

Tags: javascript, forms, match, textinput

Hi and thanks for looking.

I need to get all form inputs from a form using javascript, the inputs are named like so:

```
<input name="site[1]" type="text" size="3" id="sitesinput" value="0" />
<input name="site[2]" type="text" size="3" id="sitesinput" value="0" />
<input name="site[3]" type="text" size="3" id="sitesinput" value="0" />
<input name="site[4]" type="text" size="3" id="sitesinput" value="0" />
```

......

```
<input name="site[10]" type="text" size="3" id="sitesinput" value="0" />
```

and I have the following to pick them up and adding the values togther, but it is not working, what am I doing wrong:

```
function site_change() {
         var sites= document.getElementById('sitesinput').value;    
         var sum= 0;
         var inputs= document.getElementById('inputsite').getElementsByTagName('input');
         for (var i= inputs.length; i-->0;) {
            if (inputs[i].getAttribute('name').match(/^site[\d+$]/))
            {
             var v= inputs[i].value.split(',').join('.').split(' ').join('');
             if (isNaN(+v))
                 alert(inputs[i].value+' is not a readable number');
             else
                 sum+= +v;
            }
         }
         var phones= document.getElementById('phonesinput').value;
         document.getElementById('siteresult').innerHTML = phones-sum;
    };
```

Is the Match function wrong?

Thanks,
B.

Comment: Why do all your inputs have the same id? And why are you creating the variable `sites` and then not using it?

Comment: Right, you should have a different ids for all or otherwise make a `division` with an id that wraps all these and then `select` using the `name` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is a little off (using `[]` blocks characters, but you actually want to find square brackets so they need to be escaped. And `$` needs to be at the end). Try:

```
.match(/^site\[\d+\]$/)
```

Comment: Worked a treat - thanks! BTW - they don't all have the same ID - lazy copy & pasting im affraid and the var sites was left over from testing something!!!!!!